# Looking to select a drop down menu item based on the url the user enters the page from

Tags: html, forms, contacts

I have 10 different camp sites on a client site, I want to select a camp location based on where they what camp site they click on "registration form" from.

Currently it is a 10 item drop down, and I am looking to either do this through a url parameter (foo.com/test.html?camp=value) or something like that, but I cannot figure this out.

Hope fully you guys and gals can come through for me again!

Comment: What exactly is it that you can't figure out? How to read the query string or how to employ it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if you are using php (using query string ?camp=value):

```
<?php
$camp = isset($_GET['camp']) ? $_GET['camp'] : NULL;
$sel = ' selected="selected"';
?>

<select>
<option value="value1"<?php if ($camp === 'value1') echo $sel; ?>>
    Value 1
</option>
<option value="value2"<?php if ($camp === 'value2') echo $sel; ?>>
    Value 2
</option>
</select>
```

Not sure if you're using php, but maybe this will help anyways.

Comment: Why not set the correct option to selected afterwards?  Seems more readable and efficient to me.

Comment: @Ian how would that be done efficiently in php? Looking forward to learning something from your answer. If he is using a foreach loop of course that would make it more readable, but I didn't want to assume anything about OP's language. For all I know he's using static HTML.

Comment: He says he's only got ten different possible values, so the iteration through each is fairly negligible.  Looping will only do n comparisons, where n is the index of the selected item; with yours, you'd do 10 comparisons no matter what.  However, time-wise, yours is obviously more efficient, and considering the number of items...disregard everything I've said. :)

Comment: @Ian: Post your answer then, I would like to see what you're trying to tell me in code, because I don't think I'm following you, and would like to learn. Still not seeing how to avoid X comparisons where X is the total number of items.

Comment: @ian, then wouldnt I need 10 different forms for each selected value? I am looking to do this all through one form.

Comment: No you wouldn't need 10 forms, only 1. All this code does is add an attribute `selected` to the input if its value matches the query string value. Can you please tell if you are using php? Do you want the user to be able to change the value even if the query string is present?

Comment: Again, it all depends on how he's rendering the select list out.  With the overhead associated with parsing the DOM, after more consideration I'm definitely sure yours would be faster and more readable.  But anyway, I think something like the following would work:
 $options = $this->doc->getElementsByTagName("option");          
 for ($i = 0; $i < $options->length; $i++) {
  if ($options->item($i)->getAttributeNS($ns-uri, "value") === $camp) {
   $options->item($i)->setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
  }
 }

Comment: @Ian: Parsing the DOM? Really, how could that possibly be more efficient? I think you are over complicating things to great degree.

Comment: @Mad - I know, I am.  Which is why I've said nevermind, yours is faster and more readable (multiple times).  I thought I would provide you the code, since you asked for it.

Comment: @madmartigan i am currently not using php on my form page, but can change this to accomodate what you found. thanks

Comment: @dunivanb: What are you using to process the form then? cgi script? Third party script?

Comment: oh, to process the form I am using php (mailform.php), but the form itself is on a html page. It should be added that there is a redirect that is dependent on which item is selected in the drop down

Comment: OK then converting to php should not be an issue. Let me know if this helped you.